# Elasticsearch and symfony search for a part of a word

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm quite new to Elastic Search, maybe you can help me:

So, I have symfony and Elasticsearch (FOSElasticaBundle).

If I'm searching for a full word in title - everything is working (for example if I type "hello", I will get results where "hello" world is).

> But problem is, that, I want to be able to search for a part of word
>   too, for example if I type "hel" I want to get result where "hel" is
>   part of a word.

**my config.yml**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app:
            client: default
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            custom_search_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: standard
                                filter   : [standard, lowercase, asciifolding]
                            custom_index_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: standard
                                filter   : [standard, lowercase, asciifolding, custom_filter]
                        filter:
                            custom_filter:
                                type: edgeNGram
                                side: front
                                min_gram: 1
                                max_gram: 20
            types:
                book:
                    mappings:
                        Author:
                        isbn:
                        title: { analyzer: custom_search_analyzer, analyzer: custom_index_analyzer, filter: custom_filter, type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: VienasVienas\Bundle\BooksBundle\Entity\Book
                        provider:
                        listener:
                        finder:
```

**my php function**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.book');
    $searchTerm = $request->query->get('q');

    $searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
    $searchQuery->setParam('query', $searchTerm);
    $searchQuery->setDefaultOperator('AND');

    $books = $finder->find($searchQuery);
    return array(
        'entities' => $books
    );
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just forget to add setParam for Fields...

> ```
>     $searchQuery->setParam('fields', array(
>         'Author',
>         'title',
>         'isbn',
>     ));
> ```

Now Everything is working!